# Sent my amended tax return by UPS on July 14. Will it be accepted?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, amended-tax-return

Deadline is tomorrow (July 15) and my documents will be delivered on Thursday (July 16). Yet I managed to hand it over to my nearest UPS (the private company, not USPS) today (July 14). Will it be accepted?

Comment: What year are you amending?

Answer (score 3):

As long as you used one of the [IRS approved methods](https://www.irs.gov/filing/private-delivery-services-pds) from a private delivery service by the deadline date they will count it as timely mailing.

> Taxpayers or Tax Professionals can use certain private delivery
> services designated by the IRS to meet the "timely mailing as timely
> filing/paying" rule for tax returns and payments. These private
> delivery services include only the following:
>
> .......
>
> UPS:
>
> 1. UPS Next Day Air Early AM
> 2. UPS Next Day Air
> 3. UPS Next Day Air Saver
> 4. UPS 2nd Day Air
> 5. UPS 2nd Day Air A.M.
> 6. UPS Worldwide Express Plus
> 7. UPS Worldwide Express.

Follow [link](https://www.irs.gov/filing/private-delivery-services-pds) for DHL and FedEx options, excluded for brevity above.